# Entity Framework 5 - Edmx Code Issue - After Entity Deleted

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

On the diagram, When I delete one entity, It will display the following message:

"The following tables and views in the store model will no longer be mapped. Do you want them deleted".

Yes/No/Cancel.

If I choice "No" and save the diagram, i cannot recreate the entity again. Even by using "Update Model by Database". Also, I have been trying run custom tool on AWModel.tt and AWmodel.context.tt but without any sucess.

Any Idea? Is it a bug? I have VS studio 2013 with update 4.

Thanks!